# Interact with the tooltip in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I interact with the tooltip in jQuery?
You know, the little pop-up appearing when you hover an `<a>` element or an `<img>`.
I wanted to make that one follow my cursor when I move onto that tag. Exactly like [this](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#mouse).

Comment: This tooltip is native to HTML when setting title attribute. Native implictly means you cannot really interact with it. To get custom tooltip, you should use a js/jquery tooltip plugin

Comment: Incidentally, in reference to your clarification, if '[qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#mouse)' is exactly what you want, then *use* qTip2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part for mouse tracking tooltip: [Mouse tracking](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking)

I didn't not tried it but it seems nice: [one more](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/)

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna look at [jQuery UI's tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) or the [QTip plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/).

Comment: Yes i knew these plugin but i wanted to know how to interact with that native html tooltip... what I have to get

Comment: @NicolasPortier  http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking has a "view the source" button, if you would like to use that one then check out the source.

Comment: You can't manipulate the default tooltip beyond editing the pure text in it. You can however, use those tooltips for jQuery to create new tooltips, and if you're concerned about their looks, you can always make them mimic a default tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple jquery plugin for custom tooltip. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8NUV/1/)
You can specify `mouseFollow: true` to achieve movable tooltip that follows cursor.

**JS**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.tooltip = function (options) {

        var defaults = {
            background: '#fff',
            border: '1px solid #999',
            color: 'black',
            rounded: false,
            mouseFollow: false,
            textChangeOnClick: false
        },
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.each(function () {

            var $this = $(this),
                title = null,
                hovering = null;

            //set class
            if (!settings.textChangeOnClick) {
                $this.addClass('_tooltip');
            }

            $(this).data('title', $this.attr('title'))
            $(this).attr('title', '');

            $this.hover(
                // mouse over 
                function (e) {

                //check change
                if ($this.attr('title') != '') {

                    if ($this.attr('title') != $this.data('title')) {

                        $this.data('title', $this.attr('title'));
                        $this.attr('title','');
                    }

                } else {

                    $this.removeAttr('title');
                }

                $this.attr('title', '');

                hovering = true;
                $('#tooltip').remove();

                //create box
                if ($this.data('title') != '') {

                    $('<div id="tooltip" />')
                        .appendTo('body')
                        .text($this.data('title'))
                        .hide()
                        .css({
                            backgroundColor: settings.background,
                            color: settings.color,
                            border: settings.border,
                            top: e.pageY + 10,
                            left: e.pageX + 20
                        })
                        .fadeIn(500);
                }

                if (settings.rounded) {
                    $('#tooltip').addClass('rounded');
                }

             },
             //mouse out
             function () {
                hovering = false;
                $('#tooltip').remove();
             });

            //text change
            if (settings.textChangeOnClick) {

            //on click
            $this.on('click', function () {

                if (hovering) {

                    //set new
                    $this.data('title',$(this).attr('title'));

                    $(this).attr('title', '');
                    $('#tooltip').text($this.data('title'));
                }
            });
        }

        //mouse follow
        if (settings.mouseFollow) {

            $this.mousemove(function (e) {
                $('#tooltip').css({
                    top: e.pageY + 10,
                    left: e.pageX + 20
                });
            });
        }
    });

    return this;
}


})(jQuery);
```

**SET PLUGIN FOR ELEMENT**

```
$('a').tooltip({
    mouseFollow: true
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" title="Hello"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#tooltip
{
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #464646;
    z-index: 999999;
}
.rounded
{
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```